# How secure is application lock?

Tags: security

I have locked some of my apps using **Application Lock**. Does this only lock the individual applications or does it also add a layer of encryption on the application data? 
Just for clarification, I'm talking about the in-built setting, not an external application to lock other applications.

Comment: Mind telling us the brand and model please? This feature isn't built into Android natively.

Comment: I've seen it on following models: Xiomi Mi 3 and 4 as well on Lenovo K6